# Non-type reference parameter can be modified at run-time, does it mean template can be instantiated at run-time?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

Recently, I learned about non-type reference parameters like `template<auto& t>`.
Then I find that `t` can be modified at run-time:

```
#include <iostream>
template<auto& N>
struct X{
    int operator()() { return N; }
};

int a = 2;
int main()
{
    std::cin >> a; //stdin: 5
    auto temp = X<a>();
    std::cout << temp() << '\n';
}
```

The output is `5`, not `2`. Does it mean `temp` is instantiated at run-time?

---

I will try to answer my own question. If anywhere wrong, please correct me, thx! Other answers also welcome!

Comment: Informally, the template argument is the location of `a`, not the stored value. The location of non-local variables is considered to be known at compile-time. The code would stop working if you moved `int a = 2;` inside `main`

Comment: Thanks, @M.M So, the external linkage is required, right?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687575/6949852 find the requirement for linkage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [All the standard requires is that the observable behavior be as if the
templates were instantiated before the program started to run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979723/do-templates-actually-have-to-be-compile-time-constructs)
.

The reason for the output `5` is that reference type `auto`& here just means

- `N` will bind with `a` when being instantiated and
- the instantiation still occurs at `compile-time`.

Look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
template<auto& N>
struct X{
    int operator()() { return N; }
};

int a;
int main()
{
    auto temp = X<a>();
    std::cout << "Compile-time: " << temp() << '\n'; //output 0
    std::cin >> a; //stdin: 5
    std::cout << "Run-time: " << temp() << '\n'; //output 5
}
```

[**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UxY7MwV89knIuAbd)

Thanks for Guillaume Racicot's comment, the below is wrong.

<del>a is initialized with `0` at **compile-time** and modified at **run-time**. `N` in `temp`
changed from `0`(**compile-time**) to `5`(**run-time**).</del>

Update:

In many implementations, `a` is stored in `bss` segment and will be initialized to zero or do not have explicit initialization in the source code by `crt0` at runtime.

Comment: The value of `a` is never available at compile time. It is assigned to `0` by default though.